# How to avoid if-statements in typescript-reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, typescript, porthole.js

I have different types of action checks which does different functionalities, simply i made if and else condition to check the action type and do the relevant functionality like the below code snippet

```
public onMessage = (messageEvent) => {
    if (messageEvent.data.action === 'subscribeTriggers') {
        this.subscribeTriggers(messageEvent);
    } else if (messageEvent.data.action === 'setGlobalFilters') {
        this.setGlobalFilters(messageEvent);
    } else if (messageEvent.data.action === 'getGlobalFilters') {
        this.receiveGlobalFilters(messageEvent);
    } else if (messageEvent.data.action === 'initFromGlobalFilters') {
        this.initFromGlobalFilters(messageEvent);
    }
```

Is there a better solution to handle this kind of scenario, as i have a potential of having more actions in future where i have to come and change the code again and again, which i felt is inefficient.

Between this `onMessage` function is used as a event listener for [porthole](https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole) library (Porthole is a small library for secure cross-domain iFrame communication.) which i used to communicate in my react app's iframe

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects in javascript can be seen as an associative array where the key is the name of the property or the function.

So, you can make your call like this:

```
this[messageEvent.data.action](messageEvent);
```

WARNING (as noted by Joe Clay): with this syntax, every function of your object `this` is callable, so it can cause a "security breach", if `this` contains functions that you do not want to "expose".

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements are your friend in situations like this:

```
public onMessage = (messageEvent) => {
    switch (messageEvent.data.action) {
        case "subscribeTriggers":
            return this.subscribeTriggers(messageEvent);
        case "setGlobalFilters":
            return this.setGlobalFilters(messageEvent);
        case "getGlobalFilters":
            return this.recieveGlobalFilters(messageEvent);
        case "initFromGlobalFilters":
            return this.initFromGlobalFilters(messageEvent);
    }
}
```

ADreNaLiNe-DJ's answer would also work if your `messageEvent` string always matches one of the methods on `this` - that feels a little hacky to me though, as it would basically mean if you had a `this.definitelyNotAnEventHandler`, you would still be able to call it through `onMessage`. I prefer the more explicit approach - that's just a matter of taste, though :)

Comment: Your "explicit" approach is working and right but doesn't fill this "need": `where i have to come and change the code again and again, which i felt is inefficient`

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: It doesn't completely eliminate the need for changing the code, but it reduces the repetition. I'm just not a fan of indexing into `this` with an arbitrary string, it could cause subtle bugs. If you wanted to go that route, you'd be better off creating a `this.eventHandlers` object and doing `this.eventHandlers[messageEvent.data.action](messageEvent)` instead.

Comment: I agree with you, but nothing, in the submitted code, implies that there's something else than the called callback and the `onMessage`. But the `warning` about "security" is relevant.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: Yeah, not saying your answer is wrong :) Just providing an alternate solution.